# [JavaScript]Is there any way to excute multiple functions in parallel?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, parallel-processing

I am trying to call multiple functions in parallel in javascript.
Is it possible?
For example:
I want to get the sum of numbers(0 to 100).
First, I want to calculate partial sums of `[1,2 ... 50]` and `[51,52 ..., 100]` in parallel.

```
let sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0;
for(let i = 1; i < 51; i++) { sum1 += i}
for(let j = 51; j < 100; j++) {sum2 += j}
sum = sum1 + sum2;
```

I think I can do it in C# by using `Parallel.invoke()` but is it possible in Javascript?
Or is it possible in ReactJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is.

In NodeJS you can use fork() or [the cluster api](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html) to run concurrent tasks and listen to messages from the master node, it's not exactly a thread, nodeJS is monothread, you'd be creating new processes.

In browser you can use [webworkers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers), it's similar to threads in other languages. WebWorkers are not [fully supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=webworker) in some mobile browser.

EDIT 1: sure, here's a nodeJS example, you woul'd have to do the 'waiting' part yourself, but you got the concept.

```
const cluster = require('cluster');

if (cluster.isMaster) {
    const nodes = 4;
    const limit = 40000;
    const nEachNode = (limit / nodes) |0;


    for (let i = 0; i < nodes; i++) {
        let worker = cluster.fork();
        worker.send({ start: nEachNode * i, end: nEachNode });
        worker.on('message', handleResponse);
    }

    let total = 0;
    function handleResponse(response) {
        total += response;
        console.log(`worker answered, total: ${total}`);
    }

    cluster.on('exit', (worker, code, signal) => {
        console.log(`worker ${worker.process.pid} died`);
    });
} else {
    console.log(`Worker ${process.pid} started`);
    process.on('message', start);

    function start(conf) {
        let cumulative = 0;
        for (let i = conf.start; i < conf.start + conf.end; i++) {
            cumulative += i;
        }
        process.send(cumulative);
        process.exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: @AntonioCholony There are examples in the MDN docs linked in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript is a single threaded non blocking programming language so it doesn't offer any native support for multithreading like you would have in C# or Python. However, if your code is running on Node.js, you could use the Worker API[(Doc)](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html) or write a C++ plugin to do your heavy calculations. In a browser, I think you could use web workers but I'm not qualified to talk about it.

Comment: A help article about Web Workers: [MDN web docs – Using Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Comment: @AntonioCholony There are examples in the MDN docs linked by Rory.